# Using the <pre> tag to put code online

Tags: html, c

I'm trying to post some of the work i've done in an eportfolio thus trying to put code online.
I have a quite large C file that i have put between two `<pre></pre>` tags and it puts only about 1/4th of the code on the screen and due to this doesn't recognize some of my `</div>` tags at the end of the HTML. I guess i'm wondering why the `<pre>` tag stops at a certain point. 
I have a bunch of code up to this point:

```
if (left >= right) {
    return;
}
swap(v,left,(left+right) / 2);
last = left;
for(i=left+1;i
```

It stops right there. (using notepad++ it bolds everything from right to the last character). I tried doing multiple `<pre>` tags but that didn't work either, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Escape < characters with &lt;

Comment: @WTP: That probably should have been an answer.  As for why you need to do this, the HTML parser has to keep looking for `<` characters so it can recognize the closing `</pre>` tag.

Comment: You might consider posting the code on [GitHub](http://github.com) or a similar site.  It takes care of formatting the code for display.  GitHub in particular also lets you post documentation (README files) in Markdown format, very similar to what Stackoverflow uses.

Comment: @Keith Thompson it is (scroll down). :)

Comment: @WTP: Oops, I didn't notice that the username was the same.  (I probably would have deleted the comment, but it's not a big deal.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply because html still can be valid inside `<pre>` tags.

The easy to fix this is to replace all `<` characters with `&lt;`

Comment: Thank you so much. This was pissing me off to no end.

Answer (score 0):

In the pre'd code, you should change every `<` into a `&lt;`:

```
if (a &lt; 10)
```

Otherwise the browser thinks you mean a tag.

Any decent editor should have a command that does this for you.

---

You should also escape `&` as `&amp;`:

```
if (a &amp;&amp; b)
```